# Can't able to get json data from URL in PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

**Need:**

I need to get json data from a URL

**Problem:**

It return the null value

**Try:**

I tried both CURL and file_get_contents of method. But both not giving result

**Sample Code:**

```
<?php
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);
$url="http://techpaisa.com/chart/wipro/atr/?xhr";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$r=json_decode($result);
print_r($r);
?>
```

This code returns empty. I just tried, copy the json and putted in on my own website. Then I tried, I got result.

I got following headers from "http://techpaisa.com/chart/wipro/atr/?xhr":

```
Server: nginx/0.7.65
Content-Type: application/json
Keep-Alive: timeout=20
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 25 Aug 2016 20:59:46 GMT
X-Varnish: 462939608 462936037
Age: 3494
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
```

My Own Page Code and Header:(Skipped Some Json)

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo "{'content': 'Date,Price,ATR#1995/02/01,37.0,0.5', 'analysis_type': 'atr', 'text_analysis': 'ATR: 9.57', 'axisname': 'Price', 'analysis_type_verbose': 'Average True Range', 'image_type': 'text/csv', 'symbol': 'wipro', 'fig_title': 'WIPRO Average True Range', 'annotations': '[]', 'set_date_range': true}";
?>
```

Header Value:

```
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: Then, how I have to display json in php

Comment: In valid JSON format :)

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried

```
var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true));
```

and it works. **Your code should work too**.

If it does not, there's something else at work here.

- where do you run that code from? Perhaps there's a firewall or other mechanism that allows reading *its own webpages and scripts*, but not outside resources. This is commonly done to prevent resource abuse.
- are you allowed to read that information? If not, then maybe the webmaster has noticed someone "scraping" the data and locked out the address of your current web server. You'll still be able to read that information *from home*, it's just your PHP code on the server that will no longer work.

I am personally betting on reason #1. In that case you'll have to bring it up with whoever administers your web server.

Comment: I am running this code from my direct website url and run the url using cron jobs.

I will try with your code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks lserni

I Accept your answer.

Your code is working. But the thing is, I can't able to get value from keyname.

**Example:**

```
url="http://techpaisa.com/chart/wipro/atr/?xhr";
$result=json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
var_dump($result->content);
```

It giving following error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object myfile.php
```

But I solved this using following code:

```
$url="http://techpaisa.com/chart/wipro/atr/?xhr";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url,true));
var_dump($data->content);
```